# Group by and having "Unknown column"

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
id | user_id | done | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1  | 5       |  0   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
1  | 2       |  1   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
1  | 5       |  1   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
1  | 10      |  0   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
1  | 7       |  0   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
1  | 5       |  1   | 2017-12-23 23:28:00
```

What I want to get is the count of users who has at least one `done` of 0 (note that user_id column value can repeat multiple times)

I tried this:

`select count(*) as sum from users group by user_id having done=0`

but it says `Unknown column 'done' in 'having clause'`

How can I get the right data with MySQL?

Comment: You should use `where` instead of `having`

Comment: Because HAVING is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: I edited the question, 'user_id' value can repeat multiple times per table as shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get users who has at least one done = 0, you can use following

```
select count(*) as sum 
from users 
group by user_id 
having sum(done=0) > 0
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c286b3/2)

To get the count of all users who have at least one record where done = 0

```
select count(distinct user_id) 
from users
where done=0;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c286b3/4)

Comment: returns two rows, each with a different value and both are not right :(

Comment: @HorusCoding Include your expected data in your question and it should be relevant to your sample data, For above query it will give you the counts for each user who have atleast one record with done =  0 see demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c286b3/2

Answer (score 1):

try this one

use `where` instead of `having`

```
select count(*) as sum from users where done=0 group by user_id
```

Comment: returns two rows, each with a different value and both are not right :(

Comment: which output given